# Why are my when conditions not being met if string contains substring?

Tags: regex, ruby, switch-statement

I'm having trouble figuring out why my `when` conditions aren't being met. Each should return true when `move` contains `"n"`, `"s"`, `"e"`, or `"w"` respectively. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
loc = {x: 0, y: 0}

move = gets.chomp
case move
when move.match?(/n/); loc[:y] += move.gsub(/[a-z]/, '').to_i
when move.match?(/s/); loc[:y] -= move.gsub(/[a-z]/, '').to_i
when move.match?(/e/); loc[:x] += move.gsub(/[a-z]/, '').to_i
when move.match?(/w/); loc[:x] -= move.gsub(/[a-z]/, '').to_i
else; puts "Input '#{move}' not recognized!"
end
```

I've also tried using `move.include?('n')`, etc. with no success.

Comment: how do you know when conditions are not met? What the test input?

Comment: I think Ruby's case accepts regular expressions. You don't need to call match, you can just use /n/.

Comment: The test input would be something like `2 n`, `4 sw`, `1e`, or `3s`. I believe the conditions aren't being met because my `else` code is being executed.

Comment: @G4145, "...case accepts regular expressions." is vague.  Case statements employ the method `===` to determine if a `when` clause applies. Here that is the method [Regexp#===](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D). For example, `/a/ === 'cat' #=> true`, whereas `/a/ === 'dog' #=> false`.

Comment: You want `move.gsub(/[a-z]/, '').to_i` and so on. `move.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '')` removes all the digits, so you are left with a string of letters which, when converted to an integer, returns zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you reduce your code to something like this?

```
move = gets.chomp

case move
when /n/
  puts "called #{move}" #add your stuff here
when /s/
  puts "called #{move}"
when /e/
  puts "called #{move}"
when /w/
  puts "called #{move}"
else
  puts "Input '#{move}' not recognized!"
end
```

Just a side note about your gsub

```
move.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '').to_i
```

Shouldn't you be using?

```
move.gsub(/[a-z]/, '').to_i
```

Comment: You might want to add to the answer that you changed `when move.match?(/n/)` into `when /n/` which is the important bit here. You might also want to add why this change is needed. *"Couldn't you reduce your code to something like this?"* isn't the best explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know case statements accept regex. However, I'm still not sure why  `.match?` or `.include?` aren't working. Also, you are right about the gsub. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what input data you expect but should it be something like this?

```
loc = {x: 0, y: 0}
puts 'make a move n s e w'
move = gets.chomp.downcase

unless move[/\A[n,s,e,w]\d+\z/]
  puts "Input '#{move}' not recognized! should start with n, s, e, w,"
end

move_distance = move[/\d+/].to_i

case move
when /^n/
  loc[:y] += move_distance
when /^s/
  loc[:y] -= move_distance
when /^e/
  loc[:x] += move_distance
when /^w/
  loc[:x] -= move_distance
else
  puts "Input '#{move}' not recognized!"
end

puts loc
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes ! was typo, band changed regex too, thanks.